# TicTacToe Code With For Loops Winner... Cannot Find A Winner Why?

Tags: java, arrays, function, class, multidimensional-array

```
    //I have been working on this code for the past week on and off... the main issue I have been having is finding a winner without listing down all the possibilities...

    //THIS IS MY METHODS CLASS
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class TicTacToe1 {
        private String Player1Name;
        private String Player2Name;
        private char Pl1Choice;
        private char pl2Choice;
        private int row;
        private int column;
        private char board[][] = new char[4][4];

        public TicTacToe1() {

        }

        public TicTacToe1(String name1, String name2, char choice1, char choice2, int r, int c, char b[][]) {
            this.Player1Name = name1;
            this.Player2Name = name2;
            this.Pl1Choice = choice1;
            this.pl2Choice = choice2;
            this.row = r;
            this.column = c;
            this.board = b;
        }

        public void PlayerInfo(String name1, String name2, char choice1, char choice2) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter The Name Of Player-1");
            this.Player1Name = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("\nEnter The Name Of Player-2");
            this.Player2Name = sc.nextLine();
        }// PlayerInfo Method

        public void InitializeBoard() {
            for (int l = 1; l < board.length; l++) {
                for (int g = 1; g < board[l].length; g++) {
                    board[l][g] = '*';
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("--------------");
            for (int i = 1; i < board.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                    System.out.print(board[i][j] + "| ");
                }
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("--------------");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

    public void PrintBoard() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("--------------");
    for (int i = 1; i < board.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < board[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print("  ");
        System.out.print(board[i][j] + "| ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("--------------");
        System.out.println();
        }
        }

        public char WhoPlaysFirst() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char secondplayer = ' ';
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("\nWho Would Like To Go First???");
            System.out.println(this.Player1Name + " - 1");
            System.out.println(this.Player2Name + " - 2");
            char firstplayer = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if (firstplayer == '1' || firstplayer == '2') {
                if (firstplayer == '1') {
                    return firstplayer = '1';
                } else if (firstplayer == '2') {
                    return firstplayer = '2';
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Enter A Valid Option Pls");
                continue;
            }
        }
        }
        public Boolean IsElementExist() {
        if (board[this.row][this.column] == '*') {
            if (board[this.row][this.column] == 'X' || board[this.row][this.column] == '0')
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
        public void AddElement1() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean check;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(this.Player1Name + " Plays...");
            System.out.println("\nEnter The Row You Would Like To Enter The Element");
            this.row = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("\nEnter The Column You Would Like To Enter The Element");
            this.column = sc.nextInt();
            if (this.row >= 1 && this.row <= 3) {
                if (this.column >= 1 && this.column <= 3) {
                    check = true;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Pls Enter Values Within The Board Size");
                System.out.println("\nEnter The Row You Would Like To Enter The Element");
                this.row = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("\nEnter The Column You Would Like To Enter The Element");
                this.column = sc.nextInt();
                continue;
            }
        }
        while (true) {
            boolean poscheck = true;
            if (board[this.row][this.column] == '*') {
                board[this.row][this.column] = 'X';
                break;
            } else if (board[this.row][this.column] == 'X' || board[this.row][this.column] == '0') {
            poscheck = false;
            }
            if (poscheck)
                break;
            else {
                System.out.println("This Spot Is Already Filled... Try Another Position Pls!")
                continue;
                }
            }
        }// AddElement1

        public void AddElement2() {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean check;
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(this.Player2Name + " Plays...");
                System.out.println("\nEnter The Row You Would Like To Enter The Element");
                this.row = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("\nEnter The Column You Would Like To Enter The Element");
                this.column = sc.nextInt();
                if (this.row >= 1 && this.row <= 3) {
                    if (this.column >= 1 && this.column <= 3) {
                        check = true;
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Pls Enter Values Within The Board Size");
                    continue;
                }
            }
            board[this.row][this.column] = '0';
        }

        public Boolean HorizontalWin() {
            boolean won = false;
            /*
             * for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) { if (board[i][1] == board[i][2] && board[i][2]
             * == board[i][3]) { won = true; break; } else continue; }
             */
            char start;
            for (int i = 1; i < board.length - 1 && !won; i++) {
                start = board[i][1];
                if (start != '*') {
                    for (int j = 2; j < board[i].length - 1; j++) {
                        if (board[i][j] != '*')
                            if (board[i][j] == start && board[i][j + 1] == start) {
                                won = true;
                                System.out.println("Horizontal");
                                break;
                            } else {
                                won = false;
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            return won;
        }// HorizontalWin

        public Boolean VerticalWin() {
            boolean won = false;
            char start;
            for (int i = 1; i < board.length - 1 && !won; i++) {
                start = board[1][i];
                if (start != '*') {
                    for (int j = 2; j < board[i].length - 1; j++) {
                        if (board[j][i] != '*')
                            if (board[j][i] == start && board[j + 1][i] == start) {
                                won = true;
                                System.out.println("Vertical");
                                break;
                            } else {
                                won = false;
                            }
                    }
                }
            }

            /*
             * for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) { if (board[1][i] == board[2][i] && board[2][i]
             * == board[3][i]) { won = true; break; } else continue; }
             */
            return won;
        }// VerticalWin

        public Boolean DiagnolWin() {
            boolean won = false;
            char start;
            for (int i = 1; i < board.length - 1 && !won; i++) {
                start = board[1][1];
                if (start != '*')
                    if (board[i][i] != '*')
                        if (board[2][2] == start && board[3][3] == start) {
                            won = true;
                            // System.out.println("check");
                        } else
                            won = false;
            }
            for (int j = 1; j < board.length - 1 && !won; j++) {
                start = board[3][1];
                if (start != '*')
                    if (board[j][board.length - j - 1] != '*')
                        if (board[2][2] == start && board[1][3] == start) {
                            won = true;
                            System.out.println("check");
                        } else
                            won = false;
            }
            return won;
        }// DiagnolWin

        public boolean winner() {
            return (VerticalWin() || HorizontalWin() || DiagnolWin());
        }

    }// class

public class TicTacToe2 {//MAIN CLASS WHERE I CALL MY METHODS.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TicTacToe1 obj = new TicTacToe1();
        int counter = 1; int i = 1;
        boolean check = false;
        obj.PlayerInfo(null, null, ' ', ' ');
        obj.InitializeBoard();
        if (obj.WhoPlaysFirst()=='1')
        {
            while (i < 6)
            {
                obj.AddElement1();
                obj.PrintBoard();
                if (i >= 3)
                {
                    if (obj.winner())
                    {
                        check = true;
                        System.out.println("Winner");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        check = false;
                }
                obj.AddElement2();
                obj.PrintBoard();
                if (i >= 3)
                {
                    if (obj.winner())
                    {
                        check = true;
                        //System.out.println("Winner");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        check = false;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
            else if (obj.WhoPlaysFirst()=='2')
            {
                while (i <= 9)
                {
                    obj.AddElement2();
                    obj.PrintBoard();
                    if (i >= 3)
                    {
                        if (obj.winner())
                        {
                            check = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                            check = false;
                    }
                    obj.AddElement1();
                    obj.PrintBoard();
                    if (i >= 3)
                    {
                        if (obj.winner())
                        {
                            check = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                            check = false;
                    }
                    i++;
                }

            }
        if (check) System.out.println("Game Over!");
        else
            System.out.println("It Is A Draw");
```

/*
//THIS IS THE OUTPUT I GET BUT NO WINNER...
Enter The Name Of Player-1
Adnan

Enter The Name Of Player-2
Khan

---

### *|   *|   *|

### *|   *|   *|

### *|   *|   *|

Who Would Like To Go First???
Adnan - 1
Khan - 2
1
Adnan Plays...

Enter The Row You Would Like To Enter The Element
2

Enter The Column You Would Like To Enter The Element
2

---

### *|   *|   *|

### *|   X|   *|

### *|   *|   *|

Khan Plays...

Enter The Row You Would Like To Enter The Element
3

Enter The Column You Would Like To Enter The Element
1

---

### *|   *|   *|

### *|   X|   *|

### 0|   *|   *|

Adnan Plays...

Enter The Row You Would Like To Enter The Element
1

Enter The Column You Would Like To Enter The Element
2

---

### *|   X|   *|

### *|   X|   *|

### 0|   *|   *|

Khan Plays...

Enter The Row You Would Like To Enter The Element
3

Enter The Column You Would Like To Enter The Element
2

---

### *|   X|   *|

### *|   X|   *|

### 0|   0|   *|

Adnan Plays...

Enter The Row You Would Like To Enter The Element
1

Enter The Column You Would Like To Enter The Element
1

---

### X|   X|   *|

### *|   X|   *|

### 0|   0|   *|

Khan Plays...

Enter The Row You Would Like To Enter The Element
3

Enter The Column You Would Like To Enter The Element
3

---

### X|   X|   *|

### *|   X|   *|

### 0|   0|   0|

Adnan Plays...

Enter The Row You Would Like To Enter The Element */

Comment: maybe you are not calling `winner` ?

Comment: As correctly mentioned by @ScaryWombat, you have a `winner`-method, but you've never using it. Shouldn't the `while(true)` be `while(!winner())` instead? Or a `if(winner()){ /* Do something more here */ break; }` can be added inside the loop if you still want to do something more instead of just terminating the loop.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I actually do call it in my main... and then use a bool check to break if it's true... still no result it won't break... :((

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I added my main to the code... I did call the method winner before as well... still lost :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are loads of changes and optimizations that can be made, like using an actual 0-indexed 3 by 3 board-matrix instead of 4 by 4 like you're using now, or more efficiently use for-loops, I won't go into too much detail and only focus on your current issue.

To fix your issue, remove the `- 1` in the outer loop of both your `HorizontalWin()` and `VerticalWin()` methods:

```
for (int i = 1; i < board.length - 1 && !won; i++) {
                                 ^^^
                                 // This should be removed so it becomes:

for (int i = 1; i < board.length && !won; i++) {
```

Then your `winner()` method should work and the game should end as expected, as demonstrated in [this slightly modified code of yours to make it work online](https://tio.run/##7VpRc9o4EH7nV2zzUCBtoDadm7mhuQ7X5hrmkrZTmOY6HA/GFiDiSIxtQtOG355bycbYWLJNmuY6bZwMYGslrXb3@1aSNbMurYOZc35z02x2YWpdEhgRwmDJvXPKJsAZBFPqg80dAmPu4R2BueUHsCTkXBRbzAE@HjcaDVl2YVEG1PcXBJLt4S/RHLY0pswRPy1YUsaIh1/BlC8CcKkfiAKHL7FV1w274r5PR9SlASU@9lGpAF7NZv@42wP8P/0Ep0f943eve/DqpNPryWJ6MedeADMcW2MRULfRsy3RVVtd2vE868pvh03bruX70Kd237L7nBjwVT4W19yjl1ZAIGoNfLudLQs8MYb3rnVFPOOtdUEKZEy1jD21PJQwXk05tXXlc9fUlVMWgMeX6gKbu4sLpml0xC3PGQwHQzgERpby4eD5EP8jC8kai5FL7YSZanU0VFy8ypOMhs9w3MZTSNyZT0MNbDkmI3WHZXJI4ZcdlY2EnvWEi8Ql4rWRcIAYh@irrZMyE1KmUipyA8pEuimkYmfEUqq20CdY7ilKQqeIyopC6RQsG7VzbHzJqRNFVZeN@S0NvW1O344CIQr7Wu/KD8hFg7J6WtHoOUK5gQHFApfV9o5YgEDpI5Cljd@NI/0OjL16u8hrvt1g5HNwQhmplejrX6btzczpzczvbdVsJmwKpwTJylGbvsuQpSyXfiF/CnfVti0p6LMmwtfF7ow2fr0I0dZwCZsEU3zy5Ml2pVTFSVhxsq44cIdx3Ym6rrjWsoOJAHV1v9rOiK0q@juFsUu44yB1bTsgHhINh0QztqAFtpiFFWexLejGFjO9LbZVre0BbCunlV13NJgN4QnsXStrripF7WQNqNYs34TlWl4VEoaopw7YB8f/pI6XfH825YLY/L@o5wcZ30sRn9icOXNJf4I5YIs5llPqEqgF3oKozK5maewXzvjCdeCEnhPoc3jDQSrx8uXLkmPNZAt0ChyAsXt1M1HdVFWXhhgL9WI7pFJFQwh0gtozRV06hlqqKtrQqML1NWw/Nau6uFW3oZMWl0eChceElDq6V0BcnygbNks1bOoarmi6KofIzYShAx8xjzrwbh5QXGK8d30dUjE@cdGwIOUzWhYNf3LuEotB1z9yyQVhwdFnqkCEsFfIA@uZ3HCQmLkNpQH3lQYsVfUfGRiFYs@q9UqOcwQWs8YQXsirNbZQoJ0zB1C2rskoHceJDGlkjDiKbG1PiX3@rWSiZAHJabhSLEkFqWnjB5ydf@KLLXralEfDUjWdmN1H9NBFJr@FDq/CdcC3qBEvJfI1EVEZq/0HJlV4/HgzjheH0MrjpGRPqcrRs7z6Ia9iBKCO6oCN48Uj1vl3YxsklsisyDcL4sMZxSEwaWQ5JYIezubLzhLuMJp2iqjvH1W7RtbtmLkECazpY879/Pj5BrLerJh0VQVXqwetCddExr3DNKDRPWEbBa2rkSM0W9er7zKyHQHXF3uJvTkPMNlCx8U2nSuc@7kuccQGYt@7gg7jwRRD8j336Tr7P7rD9I/r@USCKspg5r1lMPMhgz1ksHvOYLfj6CJyfFZtl5htH3OPfsH@LfeMMi3Klpypeay5n9Z5X7mz8Hy9nZDgXlzFG5JD41tzKFyfuN1uOincEhvOkV7S85GH176Lbbrt3v2mYoEdWF6w2waJUPURdq/dKJFtQkJjY6hGTij4KDcRpnZdTOWui1h35@68pPNxuIkS9aqVV9VBL4QqJ501Q8o0NmV5OsQ0vfFdoawKc5vI1eGqJP5LoT6ruSar5zOLhm@Kl3wi1FLZMwVcLbw/Ei@g9i3BfU/YMIYYQT8SNmZCoR2xEdbJYiMERrLsPrCxdvtPh4w7Sj6xR8JbU97GPpO32uTTEqV3k3x02E6gVovs19SaMH7PwD4Ip2e7gbtU4qsUpp4SkNzIm3I6kYVjS8wcSkOxLAzRZSoUyplpHgRX@h3BQkStKqVeyyg9NyvjudbdeA6JcUuRmVDmLpxpfBdn/s@e1HHCBu8ZSojxLk/yZOggarGWngtcX2fm/vgoySr1zPpB6CFP5oS369dY8qzOqThx9LXZPO1034aHgODs@OjDEXThVefkJHFEqLGtP7ovWK/5xcGl6MjEYAiWN/G3h5M4FMRHs@hURPIITNq64UmbhVychaQW85t@Q0HtKOyukTjYwRau@xTCzypU5Uc9WyNzHqGdeZ8hxLbeAx4eitdLKclseEc7HYKmf8sCSQ0H0Vfq1UBbK5Z8J93WwpyKVXtLjeP82ZboYx2zeh7IR3W51b8O12ey96JZUsEMaaUtKeSEgh1CfetpL5q/jhebzZ/KjziH2m3XJ97BVnOGuQNnHMLvtyONXyjcfnjoGw@@@PHgm4NfYTbN@x0Vsb2RJygviZd596IclKqJbviWB1571nIvNaeTnzc3HYdZrPL3FD@Miol/Lfw25Lcpf7Uqrf8A).

With the `- 1` you were looping in the range `[1, 4-1)` (from `1` to and excluding `3`, so actually just iterations `i=1` and `i=2`). By removing the `- 1` you will loop the iterations `i=1`, `i=2` AND `i=3` as you'd want.

Comment: Saviour!!!... Thank you for ur help :))!... I was also wondering if u look at my main... if I choose the 2nd player to start first it asks me again I have no reason why ://... And I will make the array change as I complete the code... Thank You Again :)

Comment: @ManU4lifeAK If you choose the second player it will call the `WhoPlaysFirst()` method twice. Just make a variable for your `obj.WhoPlaysFirst()` call, and then do the if and else-if statement with this variable (i.e. `char firstToPlay = obj.WhoPlaysFirst();` and `if(firstToPlay =='1')` and `else if(firstToPlay =='2')`). Good luck completing your code. :) PS: In Java best practices methods/variables usually start with a lowercase, like `whoPlaysFirst()` instead of `WhoPlaysFirst()`.

Answer (score 0):

An simple way to check your win conditions without loops is to compare the rows, cols or diagonals with arrays composed of 3 Xs or 3 0s. It does not scale well if you have more rows and columns, but for a tic tac toe problem where the lengths are fixed to 3, it works fine.

```
private char[] xs = new char[] {'X', 'X', 'X'};
private char[] os = new char[] {'0', '0', '0'};

public boolean HorizontalWin() {
    char[] row1 = new char[] {board[1][1], board[1][2], board[1][3]};
    char[] row2 = new char[] {board[2][1], board[2][2], board[2][3]};
    char[] row3 = new char[] {board[3][1], board[3][2], board[3][3]};

    return Arrays.equals(row1, xs) || Arrays.equals(row1, os)
        || Arrays.equals(row2, xs) || Arrays.equals(row2, os)
        || Arrays.equals(row3, xs) || Arrays.equals(row3, os);

}// HorizontalWin

public boolean VerticalWin() {
    char[] col1 = new char[] {board[1][1], board[2][1], board[3][1]};
    char[] col2 = new char[] {board[1][2], board[2][2], board[3][2]};
    char[] col3 = new char[] {board[1][3], board[2][3], board[3][3]};

    return Arrays.equals(col1, xs) || Arrays.equals(col1, os)
        || Arrays.equals(col2, xs) || Arrays.equals(col2, os)
        || Arrays.equals(col3, xs) || Arrays.equals(col3, os);
}// VerticalWin

public boolean DiagnolWin() {
    char[] diag1 = new char[] {board[1][1], board[2][2], board[3][3]};
    char[] diag2 = new char[] {board[1][3], board[2][2], board[3][1]};

    return Arrays.equals(diag1, xs) || Arrays.equals(diag1, os)
        || Arrays.equals(diag2, xs) || Arrays.equals(diag2, os);
}// DiagnolWin
```

**Notes:**

1- You should be using a 3x3 array instead of a 4x4. Having that first empty row and columns is very error prone. I didn't notice at first and was a little confused with the loops

2 - Java convention is to write method names starting with a lower case, i.e. `horizontalWin`, `verticalWin`, `diagonalWin`

3 - There is no point returning a `Boolean`, better use the primitive form `boolean`